# Jmeter- how to extract start and end dates from System Calendar and then pass it to variable

Tags: jmeter

I need to dynamically extract start and end dates of System Calendar control.
Example: On clicking System Calendar, Start date is May 29th and End date is June 9th.
Is it possible to extract this dynamically and then pass the same to variables in the Jmeter script, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If the values are present in the HTTP response - it is possible to extract them using one of JMeter's [Post Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), depending on the nature of the response data you can use:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - for any text-based response
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor) - for HTML
- [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) - for XML, XHTML and HTML
- [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) - for JSON

Also be aware that you can use [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) to get the current time in different formats and scripting for time manipulation (i.e. add 10 business days to given date)